# how to show firebug in UIWebview IOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, firebug

i want to make a simple browser using uiwebview in IOS. Now i want to add firebug feature on that browser. I have follow some steps from this site http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite on Stable channel area, but after i include the script at the top of the `<head>` of my page, the firebug still did not appear. The script is :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>`

is there something wrong with the steps or maybe i've forgot to do something? Can anybody help me? Or give me some clues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open the site, then paste this in the address bar:

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

Comment: didn't notice that you were talking about a UIWebView in iOS.  In that case you will not have an address bar :)

Comment: i have made my own address bar, and yes i have try to paste that script on address bar, but it still did not show the firebug.

is there another clue??

Comment: This link seems to have a working bookmarklet for iOS: http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/12/firebug-for-ios-bookmarklet-adds-a-firebug-console-to-ios

Comment: thank you for your link, but i have try it before, if i try it on Safari, firebug will appear. But when i try it on my webview, firebug still not appear. Is there something different steps for uiwebview?